# devexpress gridview data disappearing

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, devexpress

I have a devExpress gridcontrol with one gridview.  This gridview is bond using EF.  I want the user to be able to insert a new row.  I have the insert line at the top.  I can enter text in the first cell but it disappears when I move to the next cell.  What can be causing this to happen?  I'm using C# and winform.

Comment: You need to post your code, as well as your create table script, for anyone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently faced with this problem.

Please be sure the `grid` have the `ValueField` correctly and your `dataTable` must have that column with same name.

The problem is `dataTable` doesn't have the column or grid's column `ValueField` may have wrong spelling or empty.

Hope it solves.